# Incorrect string format

Tags: php, string, syntax

i need help in correcting this string.

I am trying:

```
$returnStr = 'Condition<select name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value,' . ' " ' . $colName . ' ", ' . $key . ')">';
```

I want this:

```
<select name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value, 'dateTime', 42)>
```

I am getting this:

```
 <select name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value, " dateTime ", 42)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement

```
name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value,' . ' " ' . $colName  . ' ", ' . $key . ')">';
```

you have spaces each side of the ' marks hence you're getting the spaces round the colname.
If you change it to

```
name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value,' . '\'' . $colName  . '\', ' . $key . ')">';
```

you should get the result you wanted. I have escaped the '

Answer (score 2):

```
$returnStr = 'Condition<select name="lstCondition" 
              onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox 
             (this.value,' . ' \'' . $colName . ' \',' . $key . ')">';
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
 <?php 
$returnStr = '<select name="lstCondition" onchange="javascript:addDateTextbox(this.value, \'dateTime\', 42)"><option>Select</option></select>';
echo $returnStr;
?>
```